# How to fill pop up form which has two fields 'username' and 'password'?

Tags: selenium

I am learning Selenium, and got stuck at a case where at the starting of URL an alert pop-up generates and asks for username name password on the same alert pop-up.
here is the picture?[image of pop up with username and password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4d4E.png)
How can I deal with it?
there is no way I am able to select the fields with any of the methods and also when I print the page source nothing is printed.
[image of inspection of page showing no html content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaN7o.png)